# Inserting contents of CSV file into database loses 1 record

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, csv

I have an application that imports a CSV file (no header row) and writes the contents into a datatable. The datatable is then passed on as a parameter to a function in my DAL that uses the sqlBulkCopy command to write the data to a SQL Server database.

I have run tested the code as both a Webforms and Windows Forms environment and noticed that in both cases the first row of data is lost. Does anyone know why this should be the case and how I can rectify it? Thanks for any help.

I should add that this doesn't happen if the CSV file has a header row.

UI

```
Dim csvFileFolder As String = "D:\PROJECTS\Letters(DOTNET)\TextFiles\"
Dim csvFileName As String = "quad1a.txt"

    Dim connString As String = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" _
        & csvFileFolder & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"""
    Dim conn As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(connString)

    'Open a data adapter, specifying the file name to load
    Dim da As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & csvFileName & "]", conn)
    'Then fill a data table, which can be bound to a grid

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    da.Fill(dt)

    grdQuad.DataSource = dt
    grdQuad.DataBind()

    LettersBLL.TemporaryPatientManager.InsertIntoBulkTable(dt)
```

DAL

```
Public Shared Function InsertIntoBulkTable(dt As DataTable) As DataTable

    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(ApplicationConfiguration.ConnectionString)

        Using sqlBulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(myConnection)
            'Set the database table name
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tblBulkInsert"

            myConnection.Open()
            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt)
            myConnection.Close()

        End Using

    End Using
    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Dim connString As String = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};HDR=No;Dbq=" _& csvFileFolder & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"""
```

Added 'HDR=No' to your connection string

Or try  specifying your sqlbulkcopy column mappings.

msdn.....

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings.aspx

Example.....

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18418/Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still the same issue though. Have tried in both Webforms and Windows forms.

Comment: Have decided to add a header row to the text file before the insert.